# How to refer to another table's filed in mysql?

Tags: mysql

There are two tables and I want to implement something like

```
images[id].referenced = count(articles[image_id = id]) >= 1

articles:                            images:
,---------------------------------.  ,--------------------------------.
| id          | INT     | PRIMARY |  | id         | INT     | PRIMARY |
|-------------|---------|---------|  |--------------------------------|
| image_id    | INT     |         |  | url        | VARCHAR |         |
|-------------|---------|---------|  |------------|-------------------|
| name        | VARCHAR |         |  | referenced | BOOLEAN |         |
`---------------------------------'  `--------------------------------'
```

i.e. images[id].referenced is `TRUE` only if there is any article whose `image_id` = `id`.

How should I achieve this?

---

#### Update

Sorry for confusing question. I want the images.referenced  of each row updates automatically when some related articles.image_id is updated.

For example:

Initial data:

```
articles:
| id | image_id | name                   |
|----|----------|------------------------|
| 1  | 2        | First Article          |
| 2  | 3        | The author is an idiot |

images:
| id | url                         | referenced |
|----|-----------------------------|------------|
| 1  | http://example.com/images/1 | false      |
| 2  | http://example.com/images/2 | true       |
| 3  | http://example.com/images/3 | true       |
```

when a sql like `UPDATE articles SET image_id = 1 WHERE id = 2` is executed, I want table `images` also being updated automatically as `referenced` of `id=1` equals to `true` and that of `id=3` equals to false, because the article referred to image[3], i.e. article[2] is now referring to image[1].

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful... Are you just looking for `join`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the value, you can do:

```
update images i
    set referenced = (select count(*) from articles a where a.image_id = i.id) > 0;
```

A slightly more efficient method is:

```
update images i
    set referenced = exists (select 1 from articles a where a.image_id = i.id) > 0;
```

This sets the value once.  If you need to maintain the value, then you need `insert`/`update`/`delete` triggers.  I wouldn't recommend that approach.  I would suggest just phrasing a `select` query to get the results as needed from both tables.